# ROS2 cannot load custom my_package.srv

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to add my custom service to my_package.
I created a 'srv' folder under 'my_package' and add "Battery.srv" as below

```
---
float64 volt
float64 SOC
float64 current
```

and added followings to package.xml

```
  <build_depend>rosidl_default_generators</build_depend>
  <exec_depend>rosidl_default_runtime</exec_depend>
  <member_of_group>rosidl_interface_packages</member_of_group>
```

and in CMakeLists.txt

```
find_package(builtin_interfaces REQUIRED)
find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)

rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
  "srv/Battery.srv"
)
```

Also in my setup.py

```
setup(
    name=package_name,
    version='0.0.1',
    packages=find_packages(exclude=[]),
    data_files=[
        ('share/ament_index/resource_index/packages', ['resource/' + package_name]),
        ('share/' + package_name, ['package.xml']),
        (os.path.join('share', package_name, 'launch'), glob(os.path.join('launch', '*.launch.py'))),
        (os.path.join('share', package_name, 'param'), glob(os.path.join('param', '*.yaml'))),
        (os.path.join('share', package_name, 'srv'), glob(os.path.join('srv', '*.srv'))),
    ],
```

Finally in my package_node.py I tried to import

```
from my_package.srv import Battery
```

After colcon build this package successfully, to checked my service I entered below

```
 $ ros2 interface show my_package/srv/Battery
---
float64 volt
float64 SOC
float64 current
```

Now when I tried to run my package node I got error like this

```
File "/home/my/ros2_ws/build/my_package/my_package/scripts/my_package_node.py", line 14, in <module>
    from my_package.srv import Battery
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_package.srv'
```

Is there anything wrong with my practice? Any advice would be much appreciated.
Kyu

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/398222/ros2-cannot-load-custom-my_package.srv/) by [kyubot](https://answers.ros.org/users/40914/kyubot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2022-03-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just to be sure - did you `source install/setup.bash` in your workspace every time (once for the client, once for the server)? You can try to you delete your `build` and `install` folders there and rebuild everything too.

Did you create your package with [this tutorial?](https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Tutorials/Writing-A-Simple-Py-Service-And-Client.html)? Because usually messages and services are defined in another package called `your_project_interfaces` and you import everything from there. Only this part differs in your approach (e.g. based on [this](https://roboticsbackend.com/ros2-create-custom-message/) and previous link) - you try to do everything in one package, both `srv/` and scripts.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kyubot](https://answers.ros.org/users/40914/kyubot/) on 2022-03-31**:
As you said, `source ~/bashrc` did the trick and it works now.
I also realized srv file should not include any Capital letter.
Thank you for your comment!

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-03-31**:
I am happy to help! You can mark the answer as accepted then